# R function Call from Another Function

Tags: r, function

I need to modify the function gamGPDfit() in the package QRM to solve a problem. The function gamGPDfit() in turn calls other functions fit.GPD(​) and gamGPDfitUp() to compute the estimates of the parameters.

The structure of the function is shown below:

```
 #######################################################
 gamGPDfit<-function (..., init = fit.GPD(...) , ...)
 {
...
Par<-gamGPDfitUp(...)
...
return (list(...))
}
<environment: namespace:QRM>
#######################################################
```

Now, when I call fit.GPD(​), I get the function on the command window to make the necessary modifications. However, the other function  gamGPDfitUp​() returns

```
 > gamGPDfitUp
 Error: object 'gamGPDfitUp' not found
```

The question is, how do I get such an in-built function within another function? Does it have to do with the environment QRM? If so how do I obtain the function to modify it?.

I have attached the function and the call of the gamGPDfitUp() is indicated in colour red.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things that may come in handy.

One is `help(":::")` - Accessing exported and internal variables in a namespace. You can access GamGPDfitUp probably by prefixing it with `QRM:::`.

Another function is `fixInNamespace`, which allows you to modify functions inside packages. The help page for this one lists a few more interesting tools. Play around with this and it should solve most of your problems.